# How to set SystemJS config in angular-cli project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, recaptcha, systemjs

I want to use angular2-recaptcha ([Angular2-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-recaptcha)) in my project. In documentation I see that I need to config SystemJS. Problem is that I don't have this file in my angular-cli project. How can I change configs?

Comment: Angular-Cli uses webpack and not systemjs.

Comment: you don't need systemjs, simply npm install and import it